# Steps to take to make a number "beauty" in python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I was given a number N, I can customize it, for example: 156, I can increase or decrease each digit in the number, like 1 in 156 increase 1 became 256 or 6 in 256 increases twice became 158.

And a "beautiful" number is a number consists of only 3 or 7, and 7 cannot stand before 3, for example, 733 is not a beautiful number.
each time I increase or decrease counts as 1 turn, what is the minimum turns need to take to make a number "beauty"?

Here is my idea

```
Num = input()
N = [int(x) for x in str(Num)]
cnt = 0
cft = 0
cfs = 0
def checkcft(N): #check the step to change the number to whole sevens or whole threes
    global cft
    if N[i] == 9:
        cft += 5
    elif N[i] > 3:
        cft += N[i] - 3
    else:
        cft += 3 - N[i]
def checkcfs(N):
    global cfs
    if N[i] == 2:
        cfs += 5
    elif N[i] > 2:
        cfs += N[i] - 2
    else:
        cfs += 3 - N[i]

for i in range(len(N)):
    N[i] = int(N[i])
    checkcft(N)
    checkcfs(N)
    if N[i]==0:
        cnt += 3
    elif N[i] == 5:
        cnt += 2
    else:
        if abs(7-N[i]) < abs(3-N[i]):
            cnt += abs(7-N[i])
        else:
            if i == 0:
                cnt += abs(3-N[i])
            else:
                if N[i-1]==7:
                    cnt += abs(7-N[i])
print(min(cnt, cft, cfs))
```

the problem I encountered is for example the number 643, it will take 6 and increase 1 and 4 decrease 1, which is 2, but 733 is not a beautiful number, so it should be 333 after 4 turns

But when I try to fix that by checking if the prev number is 7, there're many other possible shorter ways, like the number abc, should b be decrease to 3 and c is 7 or b to 7 and c as well, which is shorter?

Beautiful number: 3, 7, 33, 37, 77,...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. I first get all "beautiful numbers" with  the same number of digits as the original number.

After that, I check the cost of all these solutions and print the best one

Hope this works for you.

```
def beautiful_number_n_digits(n):
    """return all beautiful numbers possibles with n digits"""

    current = "3" * n
    i = 1
    numbers = [current]
    while current != "7" * n:
        current = current[:-i] + "7" * i
        numbers.append(current)
        i += 1
    return numbers


def mooves(num):
    d = []
    for e in num:
        e = int(e)
        d.append({"3": abs(e - 3), "7": abs(e - 7)})
    return d

num = "643"
sol = beautiful_number_n_digits(len(num))


val = mooves(num)

mincost = len(num) * 9
minsol = -1

for elm in sol:
    actual_sol = elm
    actual_cost = 0
    for i, e in enumerate(elm):
        actual_cost += val[i][e]

    print("cost", actual_cost, "sol", actual_sol)
    if actual_cost < mincost:
        mincost = actual_cost
        minsol = actual_sol

print(f"Best solution is {minsol} with {mincost} mooves")
```

Output:

```
cost 4 sol 333
cost 8 sol 337
cost 10 sol 377
cost 8 sol 777
Best solution is 333 with 4 mooves
```